# ¿Cuál es la necesidad de hacer esto en php?

Tags: php, html, php8

¿Por qué poner el código en varias etiquetas php ? ¿tiene alguna ventaja?

```
<?php if (condition): ?>

html code to run if condition is true

<?php else: ?>

html code to run if condition is false

<?php endif ?>
```

Normalmente cuando codifico, intento poner todo en una sola etiqueta php, soy  nuevo en php, gracias por su respuesta.

Comment: Generalmente no puedes mezclar HTML con PHP, por eso te pide que hagas tu condicion If/Else dentro de la etiqueta PHP y cerrarlo para mostrar tu contenido HTML

Comment: Es un método utilizado desde casi el origen de PHP. Aunque su uso está muy extendido, de unos años para aquí se considera erróneo, puesto que no se debe mezclar presentación y proceso en un mismo archivo. Para eso se utilizan varias técnicas (MVC por ej). Te recomiendo que no sigas el método que indicas en tu pregunta

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No es que tenga ventajas de por si, es para ejecutar código HTML o de otro tipo.

Por ejemplo, si recibo una variable, digamos color, y esta es verde, pues muestra algo en verde, y si es rojo, rojo.

Entonces, para el código php + html

```
<?php
$color = "verde"; //Variable recibida por un $_POST
if($color === "verde"){
    ?>
    <div>VERDE</div>
    <?php
}else{
    ?><div>ROJO</div>
    <?php
}
```

Tenemos la salida HTML

```
<div>
    VERDE
</div>
```

---

Incluso, puedes tratar todo desde el mismo PHP sin meter código html bruto.
Esto entonces, nos dará la misma salida que anteriormente.

```
<?php
$color = "verde"; //Variable recibida por un $_POST
if($color === "verde"){
    echo "<div>VERDE</div>";
}else{
    echo "<div>ROJO</div>";
}
```

Comment: Genial! , gracias, es como encapsular mi código php para mostrar mi código html...

Comment: correcto, es una buena forma de describirlo.

Comment: @kraud Recuerda marcar la respuesta como aceptada para cerrar el tema.

Comment: gracias, estoy algo perdido. ! YA SE COMO SERRAR UN TEMA EN STAC OVERFLOW!

Comment: jaja felicidades :3

Answer (score 1):

**¿Por qué poner el código en varias etiquetas php?**

Esto se hace para mezclar código PHP con contenido HTML, o dicho de otro modo, cuando cierras un bloque PHP con `?>` te encuentras en un contexto de HTML.

**¿tiene alguna ventaja?**

Hoy día no tiene prácticamente ninguna ventaja. La programación ha evolucionado y hoy día existen muchas formas de manejar contenido de una forma más organizada, implementando paradigmas de programación, plantillas, etc.

Aparte de eso, los códigos con PHP / HTML mezclados te hacen doler la cabeza si tienes que depurar algo.

Yo particularmente, si me viera obligado a tener que mezclar PHP / HTML abriendo y cerrando bloques, sólo lo haría en casos en que tenga que introducir un amplio contenido HTML. Pero para contenido que se vaya agregando en el flujo del programa lo haría concatenado. El código queda más limpio, más claro, menos verboso y la depuración es más fácil.

Tomemos tu ejemplo:

```
<?php if (condition): ?>

    echo "Condición 1";

<?php else: ?>

    echo "Condición 2";

<?php endif ?>
```

Esas 5 líneas se pueden convertir en una sola:

```
echo (condition) ? 'Condición 1': 'Condición 2';
```

Aquí usamos un operador ternario, simplemente.

Consideremos un caso en el que haya que pasar por varios condicionales para ir mostrando contenido HTML.

Analizar, comprender, depurar este código es un infierno:

```
<?php
if (c1) {
    if (x1) {
    ?>
        <div>
          <p>
          <?php echo "x1 ..."; ?>
          </p>
         </div>
    <?php
    } else {
    ?>
        <div>
          <p>
          <?php echo "x1 false"; ?>
          </p>
         </div>
    <?php
    }
} else {
    ?>
        <div>
            <p>
               <?php echo "c1 false"; ?>
            </p>
         </div>
     <?php
}
```

Veamos el mismo código concatenando y escribiendo todo en un bloque PHP:

```
$html="";
$div="<div><p>%s</p></div>";
if (c1) {
    if (x1) {
        $html.=sprintf($div,"datos x1");
    } else {
        $html.="x1 false";
    }
} else {
    $html.=sprintf($div,"c1 false");
}
echo $html;
```

La ventaja de este código es que tienes más claridad, y si hay algún problema sólo tienes que analizar la variable `$html`. Además, con `sprintf`, hicimos algo parecido a como trabajan las plantillas, pero muyyy rústico.

Hay más, porque este código todavía puede simplificarse con ternarios, cuando esto es posible y justificado. Veamos:

```
$html="";
$div="<div><p>%s</p></div>";
$txt = ((!$c1) ? "c1 false" : (($x1) ? "contenido de x1" : "c1 y x1 son false") );
$html.=sprintf($div,$txt);
echo $html;
```

Comment: Gracias! , esto ayudara mucho a mejorar mi código.